# Найти все объекты на карте при помощи searchcontrol (поиск по организациям)

Tags: yandex-geocoding-api

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить следующий вопрос.
Во время поиска по организациям при помощи searchControl происходит отображение найденных объектов на карте. Но изначально на карте (и в результате работы метода searchControl.getResultsArray()) находятся не все возможные объекты, удовлетворяющие запросу, а только часть (первые 20). Для того, чтобы отобразить все объекты необходимо нажать на кнопку "Еще 10 результатов". Метод searchControl.getResultsArray() тоже находит только первые 20 результатов.

Как сделать так, чтобы сразу на карте и (в результате работы метода searchControl.getResultsArray() отобразились все возможные результаты, удовлетворяющие запросу?

Comment: Вам стоит добавить немного кода и тэг с языком программирования.

Comment: Поиск не позволяет выгрузить все-все объекты. Это сделано специально, т.к. это сервис поиска (чтобы выбрать наиболее подходящий вариант), а не доступ к каталогу объектов. Какая у вас задача?